# Convert Array into XML In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have Array like these:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BWY DL
            [1] => SP_GPON
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Memo
            [1] => Multispeed Network
        )

)
```

and i want to format it in XML, XML format is like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <citem>BWY DL</citem> //index [0]
  <desc>Memo</desc>// index [0]
</data>
<data>
  <citem>SP_GPON</citem> //index [1]
  <desc>Multispeed Network</desc> // index[1]
</data>
```

i tried with this code, but it didn't give right result. here is the code:

```
function array_to_xml(array $values, SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    foreach($values as $row) {
        $data = $xml->addChild('data');
        $data->addChild('citem', $row[0]);
        $data->addChild('desc', $row[1]);
    }
    return $xml; 
}
```

and the result of code above is like this(wrong result):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
   <citem>BWY DL</citem> 
   <desc>SP_GPON</desc>
</data>
<data>
   <citem>Memo</citem>
   <desc>Multispeed Network</desc>
</data>
```

Comment: You should take a look at [SimpleXML](http://lu1.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). It creates nodes while accessing them and provides an array-like interface. I'd hence suggest you did the other way around, i.e. use a SimpleXML container as an array of named items. Just bear in mind you need a root element unless you expressly deal with XML fragments.

Comment: "...but it didn't give right result."  Does not give us enough information to help you. Are you passing a SimpleXMLElement object into the function?

Comment: i updated my question, i added the wrong result of my code @TecBrat
yes, i passes that.. the xml showed, but it's wrong

Comment: That's normal, `$values[0][1]` is `SP_GPON` not `Memo`

Comment: so, how to make it be 'Memo' not 'SP_GPON' ...? @RoyalBg

Comment: how many arrays in the big array

Comment: @DimasW rearrange your array before creating the xml

Comment: could you explain in code.. i dont know how to @RoyalBg

Comment: Royal and I had the same idea. I answered in code.

Comment: The zero keys should go on one key=>values pair, same as the one keys, they are right now inconsistent compared to your xml desired output. @TecBrat gave you a solution for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your array is a little odd to me, so let's see if a tweak on the array layout is a decent work-around.

```
foreach($values[0] as $key=>$value){
  $interlaced_values[]=array($value,$values[1][$key]);
}

$values=$interlaced_values;
unset($interlaced_values);
```

**EDIT:** Attempt to clarify.

Your initial array is split into two sub-arrays. one for names and one for descriptions. I meshed them so that you have 1 sub-array for each name-description pair.

`$values[0]` is just your 'name' sub-array and `$values[1]` is your description sub-array.

I ran the `foreach()` over just the names, but accessed the matching description using `$key`.

If you'll use `print_r()` or `var_export()` on the new array, you'll see the result.

`$interlaced_values` was meant to be temporary. I assigned it's final value to $values so the rest of your code could be used unaltered. I then `unset()` the temporary variable to free up memory.

Comment: More important than getting your current project working, do you understand what I did there, and why?

Comment: actually, no.. @TecBrat .. i don't really understand about `$values[0]` and `array($value,$values[1][$key])` and what is **unset** for